# speed up the access to reporting service after recycling happens

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is there a way to speed up the access to reporting service after recycling happens?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat old article (2007), but should still apply:
[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlblog/reporting-services-staaaarrrrrtttt-up)

> if this behavior causes some business issues, you could consider modifying the recycle options on your IIS process.  You can either increase the recycle time (causing them to be recycled less frequently) or schedule the recycle to occur at a non-peak time.  You could then combine this second option with a "ping" process that hits the process shortly after the recycle.  This will "wake" the ReportServer processes so that your initial customer doesn’t see the initialization time.  If you combine these options with turning off the idle worker process shutdown, you can significantly minimize the instances where a user would run into the startup delay.

**Edit**:

The "ping" process is simply accessing http://[servername]/reportserver/.  Here's an example using VB Script

```
on error resume next

dim request
dim url
dim serverName

servername = "your server name here"
url = "http://" & servername & "/reportserver/"

set request = createObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
request.open "GET", url, false
request.send

set request = nothing
```

Save this script to your report server then use the windows task scheduler to run it.

Comment: how can i schedule the ping process?